RStudio "Run All" command vs highlighting code to run giving different output log file
I have an assignment that requires the output to be submitted to a log file. I'm using the sink() function:
log <- file("output_log.TXT ")
sink(log, append = TRUE, type = "output")
cat(readChar(rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()$path, file.info(rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()$path)$size))

This whole time I've been clicking the run all command and it shows the whole console output in my log file:
> mean(class1$math)
[1] 46.25

> mean(class2$math)
[1] 61.25

> mean(class1$science)
[1] 61.5

> mean(class2$science)
[1] 58.25

Alternatively, when I highlight all of my code and click run it shows only the output instead:
[1] 46.25
[1] 61.25
[1] 61.5
[1] 58.25

Why the discrepancy? Also, how can I show comments to be printed in the log file as well? I want the output to look like:
# What is the average math grades for class 1?`

# Answer:

[1] 46.25

# What is the average math grades for class 2?

# Answer:

[1] 61.25


It doesn't explain the difference in run all vs highlight and run. My teacher wants it to specifically look like the example above with comments while only using sink()

Then I would ask your teacher for clarification. sink() is not going to output comments. Are you sure they don't want some sort of RMarkdown/Quarto output?
